# Amount of memory deploying Grails app to OpenShift

Tags: grails, openshift

Grails documentation says:

> When deploying Grails you should always run your containers JVM with
>   the -server option and with sufficient memory allocation. A good set
>   of VM flags would be:
>
> -server -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Will it be enough for deploying to an OpenShift free gear? As I know OpenShift allows only 512M RAM for free gears. Will it be enough if I make my OpenShift webapp as scalable so that memory allocation will be double sized?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.

There are two problems:

1. -Xmx sets the maximum heap size, which in this case is more than your available RAM. So basically the app can end up starving itself.
2. The OpenShift free gear is SLOWWWWWWWWWWW!

I haven't seen any actual metrics of the performance of OpenShift gears. Redhat just mentions gear sizes and how much RAM is provided for each; but no metrics on the *"CPU"* processing speed. The free gear is small and from my experience with a Grails app running on it, it's practically unusable.

Of course, the best way to find out if it's good enough for you is to try it.